# How do I find content in ArcGIS Online which is not in a folder

Tags: arcgis-online, data-management

I have a lot of content on AGOL, most of it is divided into folders. However there are some datasets which are not in folders and only exist under All My Content. How do I find the datasets which are not in folders so I can clean up My Content?

For individual items I can see which folder they are stored in by looking at the item's properties, however this will take too long to do manually.

I can't use the filter to exclude folders.

I would rather not pay $1,000 for [CleanMyOrg](https://www.geo-jobe.com/clean-my-org/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're on the **Content** page, looking at the **My Content** sub-tab, just click on the `your_username` folder, with the little house icon.

This will show you all content which belong to you, but which are not in any sub-folder.

[image: folder list]

Comment: Thanks, didn't realise that's what that does.